# Retaining values between multiple JSPs and Actions in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl, struts2-interceptors

My Struts project structure is as follows:

`page1`->`action1`->`page2`->`action2`->`page3`

What i need is for a value i entered in an input tag in `page1` to be accessed in `action2`.

**Here is my code:**

**page1:**

```jsp
<div class = "container">
    <s:form id = "idinput" method = "post" action = "idEntered">
        Enter id: <input id = "txtid" name = "txtid" type = "text" />
        <input id = "cmdsubmit" name = "cmdsubmit" type = "submit" value = "enter details" />
    </s:form> 
</div>
```

**action1:**

```java
public class AddId extends ActionSupport {

private int txtid;
    //getter and setter

@Override
public String execute() throws Exception {      
    return "success";
}   
}
```

**page2:**

```jsp
<div class = "container">
    <s:form id = "formvalues" method = "post" action = "formEntered">
        <p>Your id entered is: <s:property value = "txtid" /></p>
        First name: <input id = "txtfname" name = "txtfname" type = "text" />
        Last name: <input id = "txtlname" name = "txtlname" type = "text" />
        Age: <input id = "txtage" name = "txtage" type = "text" />
        <input id = "cmdform" name = "cmdform" type = "submit" value = "submit form" />     
    </s:form>
</div>
```

**action2:**

```javq
public class AddForm extends ActionSupport {    
    private String txtfname;
private String txtlname;
private int txtage;
private int txtid;
      //getters and setters 

@Override
public String execute() throws Exception {
    
    return "success";
}
}
```

and displaying everything in

**page3:**

```jsp
<div class = "container">
    ID: <s:property value = "txtid" /><br>
    first name: <s:property value = "txtfname" /><br>
    last name: <s:property value = "txtlname" /><br>
    age: <s:property value = "txtage" />
</div>
```

this is where I face a problem as `txtid` is displayed as `null`, from which I inferred that the value is not passed from `page2` to `action2`

a solution i have come up with is to use

```jsp
<s:hidden value = "%{txtid}" name = "txtid2 />
```

in my form in `page2` which will allow me to use the value of `txtid` as `txtid2` in `action2`, this however seems more like a hack than an actual solution, so any other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Why do you using page->action instead of action->page?

Comment: i need to first take the id from the user which is why page1 has to be displayed first. on submitting page1 the struts action called is action1 which then displays page2

Comment: But you cut off action2, in which you want a value in txtid2, so I don't understand what do you want.

Comment: @RomanC i edited my question, only txtfname, txtlname, and txtage are displayed in page3, txtid, carried over from page1 is null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the situation where you want to keep the field values passed from one action to another you could configure the scope of the field. Just place the same field with getters and setters in each action, in your case it will be `action1` and `action2`. The field name is `txtid`. As well as [`scope` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/scope-interceptor.html) doesn't include in the `defaultStack` you should reference it in the action configuration.

**For example:**

```xml
<action name="action1" class="com.package.action.AddId">
    <result>/jsp/page2.jsp</result>
    <interceptor-ref name="basicStack"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="scope">
        <param name="key">mykey</param>
        <param name="session">txtid</param>
        <param name="autoCreateSession">true</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
</action>
<action name="action2" class="com.package.action.AddForm">
    <result>/jsp/page3.jsp</result>
    <interceptor-ref name="scope">
        <param name="key">mykey</param>
        <param name="session">txtid</param>
        <param name="autoCreateSession">true</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="basicStack"/>
</action>
```

Now you have the scope with the key `mykey` and field `txtid` under it. Providing accessors to the field in each action will make transfer field value from one action to another.

In the example above used the `basicStack` which is a skeleton for the interceptor stack and it does not include some interceptors including a [`validation` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/validation-interceptor.html).

If you need to have other features to your actions, you should either construct a custom stack or reference other interceptors in the action configuration.

Comment: this worked perfectly, thanks for the answer! seems like ill have to go back and revise some of my basics.